# Setting up Antd with meteor gives warning

Tags: reactjs, meteor, antd

I am setting Meteor with react + antd

when I import all the files like

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.less';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import 'antd/dist/antd.js';
```

I get this following warning
You are using a whole package of antd, please use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import to reduce app bundle size.

How can I set this in my Meteor.js

Answer (score 1):

antd docs say you need to use `babel-plugin-import` which loads only those components assets which you have imported.
read [Import on Demand](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started) from the docs.

for your own webpack config do

`npm i babel-plugin-import`

add this to you `babel config`

```
 plugins: [
      ['import', { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'lib', style: true }],
    ],
```

`import { Button } from 'antd';` will only load assets for `Button` Component.

if you are using `create-react-app` then follow antd docs link shared above for instructions..

Comment: I am using Meteor.js so there is no webpack  there . How can i configure then?

Comment: there should be a file `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` or `babel.json`. you need to find that file.

 i found a link to your exact same issue. [here](https://github.com/meteor/babel/issues/13). i will search abt it later and confirm u. meanwhile you can explore this link and see if people have found where it is.